# BoneCP - Add ShutdownHook to shutdown the connection pool

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, connection-pooling, bonecp

I'm using the BoneCP connection pool library and basically everything works fine. But there is one thing that I am not 100 percent sure about:

I have a connection pool that is open during the whole runtime.
Do I have to add a shutdown hook that closes the connection pool? Or could I just do nothing when the application exists?

The shutdown hook would look like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    @Override
    public final void run() {
        connectionPool.shutdown(); //shutdown the connection pool
    }
});
```

But it gives me a not very good looking log message that mixes up with my logging system because the shutdown hooks run cuncurrent. So I would not want to call this. Do I have to?

Comment: I personally expect that if the library needs a shutdown hook it should add it itself. I would do nothing here.

Comment: Calling shutdown is recommended, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9327764/3080094)

Comment: It says I should close it if I don't need it any more. But I need it during runtime all the time. So If the CP is no longer needed the program will exit any way...